# Omit norms in nest 2

Tags: nest

Hi I'm upgrading to elastic 2.x using nest with c#.
I used to use the omit-norms=true as an attribute to a property, but with the new nest I can't find the equivalent.
Where is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In NEST 2.x, [`Norms`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/scoring-theory.html#field-norm) can't *currently* be set using attribute based mapping (the property is not a primitive type, but an `INorms`).

You can use **[fluent mappings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/auto-map.html)** however, and mix with attribute based mapping. Here's an example that defines a mapping at the point of creating an index (you can also specify mapping using the Put Mapping API too)

```
var descriptor = new CreateIndexDescriptor("myindex")
    .Mappings(ms => ms
        .Map<Company>(m => m
            // infer mappings based on POCO property types and take into
            // account attribute mappings
            .AutoMap()
            // override certain inferred or attribute based mappings
            // from Automapping
            .Properties(ps => ps
                .String(s => s
                    .Name(c => c.Name) 
                    // omit norms equivalent in Elasticsearch >= 2.0 
                    .Norms(n => n
                        .Enabled(false)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
```